# How to execute a Linux utility and answer its reply in python?

Tags: python

When I am executing an utility, blab, and it will ask yes or no for confirmation, what can I do? Thanks,

The code is as below:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("blab delete {}".format(num), shell=True,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.STDIN)
stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate) documentation:

If you want to send data to process's stdin using python, create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE too.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT

process = Popen("blab delete {}".format(num), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = process.communicate(input=b'yes')[0]
output = output.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I need to answer its question not only its output.

Comment: you could send in the answer via the same procedure, calling `process.communicate(input=b'some answer')` repeatedly.

Comment: It works. I always though the input is for the initial step. Out of my surprise, it can be the input for subprocess's reply