# What is the way in python to answer a series of questions from utility?

Tags: python, subprocess

Based on [How to execute a Linux utility and answer its reply in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482760/how-to-execute-a-linux-utility-and-answer-its-reply-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top),

If the utility will ask you a series of questions, can I handle with proc.communicate()?

Comment: Many such utilities have a noninteractive option (pass the information on the command line or in a file) or a noninteractive utility that accomplishes the same things. Then you don't even have to do this.  You didn't mention what utility it is, so I can't make suggestions.

Comment: That is a openss in linux.

Comment: Maybe you mean openssl?

Comment: Does this help you?  https://raymii.org/s/snippets/OpenSSL_generate_CSR_non-interactivemd.html

Comment: Or this: https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl

Comment: Awesome! That's what I need. I used to use module OpenSSL.crypto. But as my question, is it possible to achieve with proc.communicate() or there is an alternative? Thank you,

Comment: I put comments and not an answer because I actually do not know the answer to your question :-)